Speed up SELECT JOIN query for 2 miilion rows (MySql, MariaDB)
there. I need advice to optimize my SELECT JOIN query, if it possible. I have two tables
-- dev_db_5843.hub definition

CREATE TABLE `hub` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serial_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `serial_id` (`serial_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `device_id` (`device_id`),
  KEY `ix_hub_test` (`serial_id`,`device_type`) USING BTREE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15874707 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- dev_db_5843.cct_meta definition

CREATE TABLE `cct_meta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hub_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inn` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hub_id` (`hub_id`),
  KEY `ix_cct_meta_inn` (`inn`),
  CONSTRAINT `cct_meta_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hub_id`) REFERENCES `hub` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2747768 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Table hub has 2 061 430 rows
Table cct_meta has 2 023 086 rows
I have SELECT JOIN query
SELECT
    hub.serial_id AS hub_serial_id,
    cct_meta.inn AS cct_meta_inn
FROM cct_meta 
JOIN hub ON cct_meta.hub_id = hub.id 
WHERE hub.serial_id IS NOT NULL AND hub.device_type = 1

It takes about 20 seconds
SELECT device_type FROM hub GROUP BY device_type;


SELECT serial_id, COUNT(*)  FROM hub GROUP BY serial_id;
-- 2,057,296 rows


EXPLAIN
SELECT
    hub.serial_id AS hub_serial_id,
    cct_meta.inn AS cct_meta_inn
FROM cct_meta 
JOIN hub ON cct_meta.hub_id = hub.id 
WHERE hub.serial_id IS NOT NULL AND hub.device_type = 1;


I tried to use different index variations, but it was unsuccessful. I think that SELECT 2 millions rows shouldn't take 20 seconds It should be faster. But I could be wrong.
I would appreciate any ideas to speed up the query

Apparently almost 1 million rows satisfy hub.serial_id IS NOT NULL AND hub.device_type = 1. So that index doesn't really narrow things down much, and then it has to do a full scan matching them with the corresponding row in cct_meta.

I would expect you'd want KEY ix_hub_test (device_type,id,serial_id) and KEY ix_cct_meta_inn (hub_id,inn)

@Charlieface thanks for advice, I did it, but result the same

Hard to tell without access to your system and the option to try out a few things. Often, especially on older versions, some RDBMS are not good in handle NULL values, escpecially when those columns are involved in an index. So it could be faster to make the column not nullable and use something else (let's say for example -9999999) as filter for those rows that should not appear in your result.

@JonasMetzler But setting hub.serial_id to duplicate value is impossible, because it has restriction UNIQUE. I can try any your various and post result, there is no problems for me

In this case, you could remove this constraint and use a trigger instead. Or you make sure you don't have duplicates, but always reduce the last id by 1.

device_id is indexed, but it is not a column in the table.  Please fix the Question so that it is "complete".

What is the reason for having cct_meta as a separate table?  Perhaps you have over-simplified the schema for this Question?
